# Power BI summarized or grouped? How to work out ratio

Tags: powerbi, dax, powerquery

I have spent hours trying to solve and I dont' even know what to search an answer for:

This is my base data table in Power BI

| PA | PA FTE | PERSON | PERSON FTE |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Anne | 1.0 | Peter | 1.0 |
| Anne | 1.0 | Simon | 1.0 |
| Anne | 1.0 | James | 0.5 |
| Sue | 1.0 | Andrew | 1.0 |

To help myself, I have created a grouped table, grouped by PA & PA FTE

| PA | PA FTE | SUM of PERSON FTE |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Anne | 1.0 | 2.5 |
| Sue | 1.0 | 1.0 |

I want to display on a card the result of **TOTAL SUM OF PERSON FTE** / **TOTAL SUM OF PT FTE**

Or **1.75** (which is 3.5/2.0)

If I try and create a measure on my grouped table like this:

MEASURE = SUM([PERSON FTE])/SUM([PA FTE])

I DO NOT GET **1.75**

Comment: What result you are getting? The column PA FTE may contain a different value than 1?

Comment: Another thing to check is on import, your column has all `1.0` values, so it may mark that column as an `Int64` -- Is your data [1] fixed point, [2] floating point [3] currency ? 
Then in DAX you then choose [1] fixed point, [2] decimal, or [3] whole number --- Assuming your data types are equal, is your real question why `3.5 / 2.0` appears to not be `1.75` ? Not all numbers are representable,. Here's an intro: https://floating-point-gui.de/basic/ -- One thing to note is PBI renders as Javascript -- JS has no int datatype, It has to use float, which is why visuals don't have all values 64bit

Answer (score 0):

It's better to separate out the 2 tables. When I did, Power BI automatically created a relationship between the 2 tables, which is what was throwing my total off and maybe yours too. Deleting the relationship fixed it.

**My result:**

[image]

**My model:**
Be sure there is **no** relationship between the tables.

[image]

**My DAX:**

```
Total Person FTE = SUM(Person[PERSON FTE])
Total PA FTE = SUM(PA[PA FTE])
Ratio = DIVIDE( [Total Person FTE], [Total PA FTE] )
```

**My Power Query:**

```
// Data
let
    Source = Table.FromRows(Json.Document(Binary.Decompress(Binary.FromText("i45WcszLS1XSUTLUMwCSAaklqUVQXqwOmmRwZm5+Hi5Jr8Tc1GIgbaBnCpYMLkXIOealFKWWw3TGAgA=", BinaryEncoding.Base64), Compression.Deflate)), let _t = ((type nullable text) meta [Serialized.Text = true]) in type table [PA = _t, #"PA FTE" = _t, PERSON = _t, #"PERSON FTE" = _t]),
    #"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(Source,{{"PA", type text}, {"PA FTE", Int64.Type}, {"PERSON", type text}, {"PERSON FTE", type number}})
in
    #"Changed Type"

// PA
let
    Source = Data,
    #"Removed Other Columns" = Table.SelectColumns(Source,{"PA", "PA FTE"}),
    #"Removed Duplicates" = Table.Distinct(#"Removed Other Columns"),
    #"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(#"Removed Duplicates",{{"PA FTE", type number}})
in
    #"Changed Type"

// Person
let
    Source = Data,
    #"Removed Other Columns" = Table.SelectColumns(Source,{"PA", "PERSON", "PERSON FTE"})
in
    #"Removed Other Columns"
```